# Counting theorem - fix(x)

Tags: combinatorics

I am doing a degree in Mathematics and I am currently learning some discrete maths. I recently started looking at the 'counting theorem', I need to learn my group symmetry stuff. But what does $fix(x)$ mean?

Amendment:

This is in relation to group actions and bernside's lemma. Apparently if there is some group $G$ such that for all $g\in G$ then the {$g\in G$ such that g(x)=x for a set X}

Is that anymore help with context??

Comment: Probably the set of fix points of some function (defined by ) $x$? hard to say without context. What text are you using, etc.?

Comment: fix(x) is not standard notation. The only place I can find it after a quick google search is in a section of "Frobenius' Counting Theorem" in a book by Allenby, "How to Count". Is that what you are interested in?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a group $G$ acts on a set $X$. Stabilizers (also called point stabilizers) are denoted most commonly by either ${\rm Stab}_G(x)$ or $G_x$, where $x\in X$. It is defined as $\{g\in G:gx=x\}$. The relation $gx=x$ can be read as "$g$ fixes $x$," and we call $x$ a *fixed point* of $g\in G$. Given $g\in G$, the set of all fixed points (or, expressed in set-builder notation, $\{x\in X:gx=x\}$) is called ${\rm Fix}(g)$ or $X^g$. (Indeed, if $H\le G$ is any subgroup, then $X^H:=\{x\in X:hx=x\textrm{ for all }h\in H\}$.)

Comment: So, a stabilizer is related to the group action such that what group actions have x as an in put and x as an out put. The fixes are what members of the set X have x as an input and x as an output.